# Uniform distribution problem ( probability)

Tags: probability

An agricultural company produces ajies whose weight is evenly distributed in the range [70.110]. A drawer contains 50 units and peppers weighing less than 80 grams are discarded by conciderarse guys.
If 3 drawers are filled, find the probability of dropping at most 350 grams of peppers?
I know that is distributed uniformly, then the probability of rejecting the ajie is:

$$\int_{70}^{80} \frac{1}{110-70} S \, ds$$

With this result I get a chance of rejection: $ \frac{1}{4} $

I also know that the cumulative function is:
$$\int_{70}^{X_o} \frac{1}{110-70} S \, ds$$

My question is, as I managed to get the probability of rejecting at most 350 grams having the 3 boxes of red peppers with 50 units each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X_k$ be the weight of the $k$-th rejected pepper.   Each one will have a uniformly distributed weight.

$$X_k\sim\mathcal U(70;80)$$

Let $N$ be the number of rejected peppers.   The count will be binomially distributed.
 $$N\sim\mathcal {Bin}(150, 1/4)$$

(Since, as you calculated$^\checkmark$, the probability of rejecting a pepper is $1/4$.)

We wish to find $\mathsf P(\sum_{k=1}^N X_k \leq 350)$

Now observe that $4\cdot 80 = 320$ and $5\cdot 70 = 350$, so if $N\leqslant 4$ the weight will certainly be less than $350$, however if $N\geqslant 5$ the weight will almost certainly be more.  So:

$$\mathsf P(\sum_{k=1}^N X_k \leq 350) = \mathsf P(N\leq 4)$$